# Function that returns all integer's divisors or returns the string '(integer) is prime' if its a prime number

Tags: php

Hey The solution i have got so far gives me expected results for some integers but does not satisfy the test cases ,(codewars https://www.codewars.com/kata/find-the-divisors/train/php)

```
function divisors($integer) {

    $array = [];

    if($integer<=1)
        return false;

    for($i = 2 ; $i <= sqrt($integer) ; $i++){
        if($integer% $i == 0){
            array_push($array,$i);
        }     
    }

    if (empty($array)){
        return $integer. " is prime";
    }else{
        return implode( ", ", $array );
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated , right now i get the following error

```
3' does not match expected type "array"
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You are terminating the loop to soon, just look at what the sqrt() of these numbers is.

Terminate the loop at a half of interger instead

```
function divisors($integer) {

    $array = [];

    if($integer<=1)
        return false;

    $end = $integer / 2;
    for($i = 2 ; $i <= $end; $i++){
        if($integer % $i == 0){
            $array[] = $i;      // more efficient than array_push if youare just pushing on thing
        }     
    }

    if (empty($array)){
        return $integer. " is prime";
    }else{
        return $array;
    }
}
```

RESULT

```
2, 3, 4, 6
5
13 is prime
```

Comment: true thanks for pointing that, It gives correct results  but still gives me failed test case saying '3, 5' does not match expected type "array".

Comment: Try returning the Array and not the exploded array

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for all the input, Following solution, passed all the test cases

```
function divisors($integer) {
    $array = [];

     if($integer >1)
    {
      for($i = 2 ; $i < $integer ; $i++){
         if($integer% $i == 0){
            $array[] = $i;
         }    
      }

        if (empty($array)){
            return $integer. " is prime";
        }
        else{
        return $array;
        }

    }//close if($integer>1)

  }//END function divisors
```